# Testing if a variable is a float string

Tags: php, variable-types

I know which type of variable `$value` should be.  Should `is_numeric()` be used to test whether it is a float string?

```
private function sanitize($value, $type) {
    switch($type) {
        case 'boolean':
        if(!is_bool($value)) $value=filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        break;
        case 'integer':
        if(ctype_digit($value)) $value=(int)$value;
        break;
        case 'float':
        if(is_numeric($value) && !is_float($value)) $value=(float)$value;
        break;
        //case 'string':case 'object':case 'array':    //Not sanitized
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with float string? Either it's a string or it's a float.

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky  Thank you.  Off topic, but would you recommend `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` over `ctype_digit()`?

Comment: I'd recommend throwing this whole function away and just using `filter_var()` directly.

Comment: Do you mean if its a string and a float at the same time?

Comment: @BobbyAxe  something like `'1234.567'`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky  Maybe so, but `FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN` has got me stumped as it returns `FALSE` upon validating a valid false value.

Comment: `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`